# Actualizar campo de una tabla con el valor que ese mismo campo tiene en otra tabla

Tags: sql, update

Tengo una tabla de artículos para vender (`ARTICULOS_TBL`) a los que clasifico en un campo de dicha tabla por familia (campo `CODFAM`). Es decir, se da el caso de que hay gran cantidad de artículos que pertenecen a la misma familia. En total habrá alrededor de 18.000 artículos.
Ahora bien, se ha decidido cambiar el criterio de clasificación de las familias, ya que se ha comprobado que no es práctico. Para ello he creado una nueva tabla (`CONVERSION_TBL`) en la que hago la "conversión": a cada código de familia (`CODFAM`) le asocio un nuevo valor en dicha tabla (`CODFAM_NEW`).
Para ello he creado una consulta como la siguiente, que no le gusta:

```
UPDATE articulos_tbl  A
SET A.codfam=
       (SELECT CONVERSION_TBL.codfam_new
        FROM CONVERSION_TBL
        WHERE CONVERSION_TBL.codfam=A.codfam)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT CONVERSION_TBL.codfam
              FROM CONVERSION_TBL
              WHERE CONVERSION_TBL.codfam=at_articulos_tbl.codfam);
```

El error que me da es el siguiente, pero no lo entiendo muy bien (no tengo tanto nivel):

> ```
> "Integrity cosntrains violated - parent key not found.
>
> Cause: A foreign key value has no matching primary key value
> Action: Delete the foreign key or add a matching priumary key."
> ```

Help...!! y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estás actualizando datos en la tabla **articulos_tbl** que referencia a otra tabla la cual no incluye ese dato como clave primaria.

No es muy facil decir que campo puede ser sin ver la estructura de **articulos_tbl**.

Como te sugiere el motor de base de datos (parece ser PostgreSQL) podés eliminar la clave foranea, hacer la actualización y luego volver a crear la clave foranea, pero te va a dar nuevamente el error ya que no se incluye el valor referenciado en la otra tabla, pero tal vez así, te sea mas fácil encontrar el valor faltante.

Saludos y espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, blov80. Resuelto...!!